# not able to connect to service fabric using powershell

Tags: azure-service-fabric, azure-powershell

When trying to connect to Azure service fabric I get the following error. I am able to deploy and connect to application and also connect to service fabric explorer in the web browser. But when I try to connect to using powershell it fails.

```
$ConnectArgs = @{  ConnectionEndpoint = 'tktdestsfsdsd.westus.cloudapp.azure.com:19000';  X509Credential = $True;  StoreLocation = 'CurrentUser';  StoreName = "MY"; ServerCommonName = "westus.cloudapp.azure.com"; FindType = 'FindByThumbprint';  FindValue = "9C2D2DC3F29DFBA8E7F3C92B2C27155A327573E"   }
Connect-ServiceFabricCluster @ConnectArgs 


WARNING: Failed to contact Naming Service. Attempting to contact Failover Manager Service...
WARNING: Failed to contact Failover Manager Service, Attempting to contact FMM...
False
Connect-ServiceFabricCluster : Failed to authenticate server identity
At line:3 char:1
+ Connect-ServiceFabricCluster @ConnectArgs
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Connect-ServiceFabricCluster], FabricServerAuthenticationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TestClusterConnectionErrorId,Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.ConnectCluster
```

Comment: Did the answers help?

Answer (score 0):

Are you following any specific Azure doc for this?
If not, I would recommend going through the following doc on Connecting to Service Fabric using PowerShell: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-connect-to-secure-cluster

Let me know if you still see issues. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're missing the `ServerCertThumbprint` argument value.

```
Connect-ServiceFabricCluster -ConnectionEndpoint`                     
 tktdestsfsdsd.westus.cloudapp.azure.com:19000`  
 -X509Credential -ServerCertThumbprint 9C2D2DC3F29DFBA8E7F3C92B2C27155A327573E`  
 -FindType FindByThumbprint -FindValue 9C2D2DC3F29DFBA8E7F3C92B2C27155A327573E`  
 -StoreLocation CurrentUser -StoreName My
```